# Various densities of the set of Lipschitz function

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I am curious to know the relationship between the set $Lip(X)$ of lipschitz functions and the all the sets $C(X), C_{0}(X), C^{k}(X), C_{c}(X), C^{\infty}(X), C_{0}^{\infty}(X)$ regarding density.

If you know where the set of Lipschitz functions is dense (and can reference) I'd appreciate very much. Also, I should mention that I am particularly curious about the cases $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $X=\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\Omega$ is compact.

Answer (score -3):

No matter what measure you put on the set of functions, the Lipschitz functions will always have measure 0 in the set continuous functions, therefore they are not dense. In fact, it can be proved that they are nowhere dense.

Comment: Could you add some reference to your answer? This would be a better help to the asker and to the ones wanting to upvote your work...

Comment: look at my name :)

Comment: Ok, but we are talking about how your answer is useful, not about how much you are reputable ;) 

Comment: I'm confused. Is your name meant to be in reference to [Terence Tao](https://mathoverflow.net/users/766/terry-tao)? Either way, an argument from authority is generally of poor form; you could simply provide a proof, or a reference to one.